# How to use filter on a nested jinja2 template

Tags: kubernetes, templates, ansible, base64, jinja2

I have 2 templates in my Ansible playbook:

*template-1.yaml.j2*:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": {{ (user.name + ':' + user.pass) | b64encode }}
        }
}
```

*template-2.yaml.j2*:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: '{% include "template-1.yaml.j2" %}'
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: pull-secret
  namespace: default
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

The nested template works great, but I want `template-2.yaml.j2` to encode `template-1.yaml.j2` in **base64**, I tried adding a filter like so:

`{% include "template-1.yaml.j2" | b64encode %}`

And it fails with the following error:

`An unhandled exception occured while running the lookup plugin 'template'. Error was a <class 'jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound'>, original message: dGVtcGxhdGUtMi55YW1sLmoy`

What actually happens is that the literal string `template-2.yaml.j2` is encoded and fails.

Is there any solution beside separating the templates to different tasks in my Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the following line (wrong):

```yaml
.dockerconfigjson: '{% include "template-1.yaml.j2" | b64decode %}'
```

with (right):

```yaml
.dockerconfigjson: '{{ lookup("template", "template-1.yaml.j2") | b64encode }}'
```

The [`template` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_lookup.html) will fetch the result of the given template as a string which can then be passed to the `b64encode` filter